# How to use file_field_tag with carrierwave

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, carrierwave, form-for

I was trying to optimise my project with helpers and faced a problem.
My .erb before optimisation was looking like:

```
# app/views/object/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(@object) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :image %>
<%= f.file_field :image %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

After optimisation I want to see:

```
# app/views/object/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(@object) do |f| %>
<%= f.labeled_image :image %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper

class ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
include ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper
include ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper
include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
include ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper

def labeled_image (name, options = {})
  label = label_tag @object_name + "[#{name}]", I18n.t(name)
  file_field = file_field_tag @object_name + "[#{name}]"
  content_tag 'div', label+file_field
end

end

end
```

There is no error in this code. Moreover it generates properly code but carrierwave doesn't take the file I send.

I've found only this workaround:

```
# app/views/object/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(@object) do |f| %>
<%= f.labeled_image f, :image %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper

class ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
include ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper
include ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper
include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
include ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper

def labeled_image (f, name, options = {})
  label = label_tag @object_name + "[#{name}]", I18n.t(name)
  file_field = f.file_field name
  content_tag 'div', label+file_field
end

end

end
```

But it looks like noob :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple

Just `self.file_field name` instead.